# Camera Plugin PhoneGap (iOS)

Tags: android, ios, html, phonegap-plugins

I am working on camera plugin in phone gap(iOS) . I want to fetch all media files but facing major problem because only pictures are opening from gallery and videos could not fetch from gallery. Take a look at my code and give suggestions.

My html code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <title>camera</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
  <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
  <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
  <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
  <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
  <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe your question more detailed - what's your problem?

Comment: i use camera and media capture plugin and want to fetch video from gallery and want to take snapshot